# How to tell Hibernate to not Load a Object?

Tags: java, hibernate, orm, mapping, many-to-many

Hello Stackeroverflowers,

i'd like to ask how i can solve the following problem:

I have 3 Tables:

Hardware

PC

Software

They have a Many-to-Many Relation. So N Hardware Entries can have M Hardware Entries.

When im Calling my Hibernate stuff then i get all Pc's with the chosen Software. In Software i have a Mappign on Hardware to get the specified Hardware of a Pc. 
So far so good.

The Problem im facing is that i have to make this compatible from the other side to allow to get all Pc's with the specified Hardware and then from the Pc's the software.

When i have a mapping that links from Software over Pc to Hardware its ok. When i put a mapping into Hardware to get Pc's. Im getting a Stackoverflow because Hibernate tries to create everytime i initialize a Hardware to initialize a Pc and Pc tries then to initialize a Hardware so i get a Loop that never ends.

Can someone give me a hint to Solve this problem ?

I heard of that the attribute inverse can solve this but i dont know where ro place it and how it works.

I'm thankful for every Comment.

Hardware.hbm.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN"
"http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">
<!-- Generated 04.11.2013 17:30:12 by Hibernate Tools 3.4.0.CR1 -->
<hibernate-mapping>
    <class name="de.test.database.pojo.Hardware" table="object" schema="XXX">
        <id name="id" type="int">
            <column name="id" />
            <generator class="assigned" />
        </id>
        <property name="fkserialId" type="int">
            <column name="fk_serial_id" not-null="true" />
        </property>
        <property name="name" type="string">
            <column name="name_id" not-null="true" />
        </property>
        <set name="linkHardwareToSoftware" table="pc_link" inverse="true" lazy="true" fetch="select">
            <key foreign-key="none">
                <column name="fk_serial_id" not-null="true" />
            </key>
            <one-to-many class="de.test.database.pojo.PC" />
        </set>   

    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

PC.hbm.xml

```
<hibernate-mapping>
    <class name="de.test.database.pojo.pc" table="pc_link" schema="xxx">
        <id name="id" type="int">
            <column name="id" />
            <generator class="assigned" />
        </id>
        <property name="sort" type="int">
            <column name="sort" not-null="true" />
        </property>
        <property name="owner" type="string">
            <column name="owner" not-null="true" />
        </property>
        <many-to-one name="hardware" class="de.test.database.pojo.hardware" fetch="select">
            <column name="fk_serial_id" not-null="true" />
        </many-to-one>
        <many-to-one name="software" class="de.test.database.pojo.Software" fetch="select">
            <column name="fk_sw_id" not-null="true" />
        </many-to-one>
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

Software.hbm.xml

```
<hibernate-mapping>
    <class name="de.test.database.pojo.Software" table="object" schema="xxx">
        <id name="id" type="int">
            <column name="id" />
            <generator class="assigned" />
        </id>
        <property name="fkswId" type="int">
            <column name="fk_sw_id" not-null="true" />
        </property>
        <property name="name" type="java.lang.Integer">
            <column name="name" />
        </property>
        <property name="company" type="java.lang.Integer">
            <column name="company" />
        </property>
        <set name="linkSWToHardware" table="pc_link" inverse="true" lazy="true" fetch="select">
            <key foreign-key="none">
                <column name="fk_sw_id" not-null="true" />
            </key>
            <one-to-many class="de.test.database.pojo.pc" />
        </set>   

    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

HibernateCode.java

```
try
{
    String obj =" AND t.fkHWtypeId =:otid";
    if(objectType==0) 
        obj="";

    Session ses = getSession();
    Query query =  ses.createQuery(
    " FROM hardware t"+
    " WHERE t.deleted = 0 AND t.Id =:pid"+obj
    );

    query.setParameter("pid", HardwareId);

    if(objectType!=0){
        System.out.println("Reading HWtypeid...");
        query.setParameter("HWtypeid", HardwareType);
    }


    List<Tree> list = query.list();

    return list;

} catch (HibernateException e)
{
    return null;
}
```

Stacktrace:

org.codehaus.jackson.map.JsonMappingException: Infinite recursion (StackOverflowError) (through reference chain: de.test.database.pojo.Pc["hardware"]->de.test.database.pojo.Hardware_$$_javassist_109["linkHardwareToSoftware"]->org.hibernate.collection.internal.PersistentSet[0]->de.test.database.pojo.pc["object"]->de.test.database.pojo.Hardware_$$_javassist_109["linkHardwareToSoftware"]
at org.codehaus.jackson.map.ser.std.BeanSerializerBase.serializeFields(BeanSerializerBase.java:164)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.ser.BeanSerializer.serialize(BeanSerializer.java:112)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.ser.std.CollectionSerializer.serializeContents(CollectionSerializer.java:72)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.ser.std.CollectionSerializer.serializeContents(CollectionSerializer.java:23)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.ser.std.AsArraySerializerBase.serialize(AsArraySerializerBase.java:86)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.ser.BeanPropertyWriter.serializeAsField(BeanPropertyWriter.java:446)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.ser.std.BeanSerializerBase.serializeFields(BeanSerializerBase.java:150)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.ser.BeanSerializer.serialize(BeanSerializer.java:112)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.ser.BeanPropertyWriter.serializeAsField(BeanPropertyWriter.java:446)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.ser.std.BeanSerializerBase.serializeFields(BeanSerializerBase.java:150)

Comment: So, we're supposed to fix unknown code causing an exception with an unknown stack trace when some unknown piece of code is executed, right?

Comment: No i need only to know where the Problem can occur. I will give u the code in a second

Comment: Code is now given in question. Please Ignore the proerties theyre even right.

Comment: There's no code at all in the question. Only XML mapping. And still no stack trace either.

Comment: i forgot to post the stacktrace and code. Excuse that.

Comment: i hope i did not forgot anything

Answer (score 1):

As the stack trace indicates, the problem has nothing to do with the mapping and with loading data from the database with Hibernate. The problem happens when you're serializing your beans with Jackson, because you have bidirectional associations and thus cyclic references which cause Jackson to loop endlessly.

So, you should choose how you want to serialize your objects, and use Jackson annotations or use DTOs to serialize them and break the cycles between objects. You could, for example, add a `@JsonIgnore` on the `linkHardwareToSoftware` field, so that the collection of software is not serialized when serializing a Hardware instance.

Comment: thank you very much for your answer can you explain me how to handle this through DTO's?  i have no clue.

Comment: Copy what you want to marshall to other objects (the DTOs), and make sure there is no cyclicd dependencies in the DTOs, i.e. the DTO can be represented as JSON.

Comment: okay, you mean i could make a DTO for PC with the same values even initialized to use this ? Sry, im not so familiar with Hibernate and Json marshalling.